# Laravel - Model filter date field by month

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, php-5.5

I have a method that can receive a parameter of **"month"** and another of **"year"**, you can receive both or only one of them.

In the case of *only receiving the month* I want to make a query that I look for in a field that is called **"created_at"** just looking for the **month** of that field date

At the moment I use this code but when doing a like it does not do it correctly

```
        else if ($request->has('month')) {
        $month = $request->input('month');
        $currentTimestamp = date_create_from_format('n', $month)->getTimestamp();
        $currentDate = date('m', $currentTimestamp);
        $filters['updated_at'] = $currentDate;
        unset($filters['month']);
    }

        $cars = Car::where(function($query) use($filters) {
        foreach ($filters as $column => $value) {
            if ($column === 'updated_at') {
                $query->where($column, 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%');
                continue;
            }
            $query->where($column, 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%');
        }
    })->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Is `created_at` a timestamp column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try this:

```
if ($request->has('month')) {
   $month = $request->input('month');
   Car::whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = '.$month)->get();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [whereMonth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses) method, like this:

```
$cars = Car::whereMonth('created_at', '12')->get();
```

Example with determining if a month value is exist:

```
if ($request->has('month')) {
   $cars = Car::whereMonth('created_at', $request->input('month'))->get();
}
```

Comment: This answer is more practical base on the API and answer to the question even: filter by Month, Year or Day. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel **queryBuilder** .
The idea is pretty simple. Build your query and execute it only when needed

```
carQuery = Car::newQuery();
if ($request->has('month') {
   carQuery->where('created_at' .. do camparison you want);
}
if ( $request->has('year') {
   // add extra query filter
}
cars = carQuery->get();
```